# What is the difference between mysqli_prepare() and mysqli_stmt_prepare()?

Tags: php, mysqli

[This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) of the PHP manual uses `mysqli_prepare()` here but `mysqli_stmt_*` for everything else.

However, in [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) of the PHP manual, it uses `mysqli_stmt_prepare()`

What is the difference between these? Can I use either? And if `mysqli_prepare()` is valid, does that mean `mysqli_bind_param()` is valid?

OK, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-bind-param.php) for `mysqli_bind_param()` says it's an alias for `mysql_stmt_bind_param()`. I guess it's safe to assume it's the same with `mysqli_prepare()` and the rest of the `mysqli_*` functions?

Comment: FYI (if anyone finds this on Google, the `mysqli_bind_param()` alias is deprecated/removed so `mysqli_prepare()` works (`mysqli_stmt_prepare()` doesn't) but make sure you use `mysqli_stmt_*` for everything else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mysqli_prepare()` is basically just a shortcut for

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: so instead of doing `$query = mysqli_stmt_init($db); mysqli_stmt_init_prepare($query, 'SELECT...');` I just do `$query = mysqli_prepare($db, 'SELECT...');`?

Comment: OK, thanks. it upsets my OCD that you have to use `_stmt_` for every other function but not this, although it's convenient anyway. thanks again.

Comment: if you're ocd, then you shouldn't be using PHP. php function names are determined by throwing darts into an unflushed toilet... ya never know what you're going to end up with.

Comment: @MarcB, that statement "PHP function names..." is going up on my wall because it made me chuckle as it perfectly embodies the struggles I've been having (and still do sometimes) when trying to figure out what function to use in PHP to get something done. :-)
(Yes, I know this is an old thread but it answered a question I had for some time)